# Database type of Firebase's Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Looking at the four prominent NoSQL database type (key-value pair, document store, graph store and Wide column store), in which category would Firebase's Realtime Database fall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database is a hierarchical store of key-value pairs.